# React unique key prop on h4

Tags: reactjs

I cant figure out why my code is returning this error:
"Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop."

My code:

```
const TextBlock = ({title, text}) => {
    return (
        <div className="text-block pt-160">
            <h4 className="subtitle">
                {title}
            </h4>
            <h3 className="pt-20">
                {text}
            </h3>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I tried to insert some ids using lodash _.unique id function nothing changed. After removing h4 tag error is gone.

Can someone explain why this happens and how to solve this?

EDIT
I'm calling it like this:

```
<TextBlock 
    title={['Our ', <span>works</span>]}
    text={'...'}/>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you call `TextBlock` ?

Comment: @0stone0
`
<TextBlock
                            title={['Our ', <span>works</span>]}
                            text={'One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a horrible vermin.'}
                        />
`

Comment: Are you creating <Textblock/> components in a for loop?

Comment: No, there is no loop around it :/, not map and not for with pushing elements to array

Answer (score 1):

```
title={['Our ', <span>works</span>]}
```

Since this is an array, then when you try to render `<h4 /**/>{title}</h4>`, you are putting an array as a child of an `h4`. Elements in arrays need to have keys, but that span doesn't have one, so you get that error.

I would recommend changing your title prop to be a [fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) instead of an array:

```
title={(
  <React.Fragment>
    Our <span>works</span>
  </React.Fragment>
)}
```

Or using the fragment shorthand:

```
title={<>Our <span>works</span></>}
```